# Checking existing 'wired up' methods

Tags: c#, events, methods, delegates

I may be misunderstanding something fundamental here as I'm new to these concepts so please bear with me.

I'm currently removing methods from an event like so:

```
scheduleView.TouchDown -= scheduleView_TouchDown;
```

And then on other occasions - adding the methods:

```
scheduleView.TouchDown += scheduleView_TouchDown;
```

It all works fine so far, and I can understand it's possible to add several methods, like so:

```
scheduleView.TouchDown += scheduleView_TouchDown;
scheduleView.TouchDown += scheduleView_AnotherTouchDownEventHandler;
```

But how would I then later check what methods were wired up to this event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interestingly, *you can't* (at least, from the outside). An `event` is only *obliged* to offer 2 accessors - `add` and `remove`. There are other accessor methods defined in the CLI spec, but they aren't used in C# or anywhere else AFAIK. The key point: we can't ask an `event` what is subscribed (and indeed, we shouldn't need to know). All you can do is: `add` or `remove`.

If you are worried about double-subscribing, then note that if you try to unsubscribe and you haven't actually subscribed, then under every sane implementation this is simply a no-op; which means you can do:

```
// make sure we are subscribed once but **only** once
scheduleView.TouchDown -= scheduleView_TouchDown;
scheduleView.TouchDown += scheduleView_TouchDown;
```

From the perspective of the code raising the `event`, you rarely need to know *who* - simply:

```
// note I'm assuming a "field-like event" implementation here; otherwise,
// change this to refer to the backing-field, or the delegate from the
// event-handler-list
var handler = TouchDown;
if(handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty); // or similar
```

There is also a way to break the delegate list into individual subscribers, but it is very rarely needed:

```
var handler = TouchDown;
if(handler != null) {
    foreach(EventHandler subscriber in handler.GetInvocationList()) {
        subscriber(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The main uses for this are:

- when you want to perform exception-handling on a per-subscriber basis
- when the delegate returns a value or changes state, and you need to handle that on a per-subscriber basis

Comment: Thanks Marc. As it stands - my code is written to avoid any possibility of double-subscribing as you've recommended, my question was more curiosity than anything. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: If you are **within** the class that publishes the Event, you can just access the delegate, and you can call the `GetInvocationList` method to get a list of the subscribers.

No: If you are working **outside** the class, as the delegate is not exposed to you. You could use reflection to get at it, but that would be a hack, at best.

Answer (score 1):

In the type that declares the event, you can use `GetInvocationList()` to find out which delegates are subscribed:

```
public class EventProvider
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    protected virtual void OnSomeEvent(EventArgs args)
    {
        if (SomeEvent != null)
        {
            var delegates = SomeEvent.GetInvocationList();
            foreach (var del in delegates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has subscribed to SomeEvent", del.Method.Name);
            }
            SomeEvent(this, args);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseSomeEvent()
    {
        OnSomeEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        EventProvider provider = new EventProvider();
        provider.SomeEvent += Callback1;
        provider.SomeEvent += Callback2;
        provider.RaiseSomeEvent();
    }

    public static void Callback1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callback 1!");
    }

    public static void Callback2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callback 2!");
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Callback1 has subscribed to SomeEvent
Callback2 has subscribed to SomeEvent
Callback 1!
Callback 2!
```